# How can I create a new page on Site Settings page, Site collection Administration section?

Tags: 2010, application-pages, site-settings

How can I create a new page on Site Settings page, Site collection Administration section?

I already know how to do it on central administration, but how to do it in this section for each site collection administration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom action with right location. In your case it should be:

```
<CustomAction
        Id="MyNewPage"
        GroupId="SiteCollectionAdmin"
        Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
        Sequence="40"
        Title="My new page"
        Description="Description">
        <UrlAction Url="_layouts/mynewpage.aspx" />
        </CustomAction>
```

And you need to deploy it inside a feature with the right scope - Farm or WebApplication if you want this customization to appear in every site collection. Here's teh list of all avilable locations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb802730.aspx

Comment: where do I put the code of the customaction?

Comment: nevermind, I think this link explains it all. http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-create-a-simple-custom-action-using-visual-studio-2010/